# How to add "browse" button in image in CKE Editor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I wanted to put "browse" button in image button iframe(pop up).

But I am unable to put it.

How can I change the default behaviour and customize pop up screen in cke editor buttons ?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce)  module will solve your problem !

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

Answer (score 0):

I like IMCE too, if using wysiwyg bridge module maybe you can try

- http://drupal.org/project/kcfinder
- http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg
- http://drupal.org/project/tinybrowser